Django Static Files Not Loading from AWS S3 After Running collectstatic
I'm working on a Django project where I want to store and serve static files using AWS S3. I have followed the usual configuration steps and set up my settings.py to use S3 for static files. However, after running collectstatic, my static files are not loading, and I can't access them through the S3 bucket.
Here's a summary of what I've done so far:
Configuration in settings.py:
# AWS Credentials
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'my-access-key'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'my-secret-key'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'my-bucket'

# S3 Static File Settings
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = f'{AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME}.s3.amazonaws.com'
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = 'public-read'
AWS_LOCATION = 'static'
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
    'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400',
}

# Static Files Settings
STATIC_URL = f'https://{AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/static/'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'

# Directories
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'setup/static'),
]


What I've Tried:

Running collectstatic:

Command: python manage.py collectstatic
Output says: 0 static files copied to 'static/', 176 unmodified.

S3 Bucket Permissions:

I’ve set the bucket policy to allow public access:
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "s3:GetObject",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::cats-gallery-amanda/static/*"
    }
  ]
}



Checking Files in S3:

After running collectstatic, there are no files in the S3 bucket under static/.

Attempted Solutions:


Verified that django-storages and boto3 are installed.
Double-checked AWS credentials.
Ensured that the S3 bucket is publicly accessible.
Tried manually uploading files to S3, and they work fine.

What Am I Missing?
I can't figure out why collectstatic isn’t uploading the static files to the S3 bucket. Do I need to configure something else? How can I get the static files to upload and serve correctly from S3?
Any advice or troubleshooting tips would be appreciated!

So where should Django collect the static files, is there anything in setup/static?

What Django version do you use: STATICFILES_STORAGE is removed in Django-5.1: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/releases/5.1/#features-removed-in-5-1

@willeM_VanOnsem I am using 5.1.1. My static files are inside setpu/static. I also removed STATICFILES_STORAGE and nothing changed. It is loading to my old static folder.

I replaced
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'

with
STORAGES = {
   "default": {
        "BACKEND" : "storages.backends.s3boto3.S3StaticStorage",
    },

    "staticfiles":  {
        "BACKEND" : "storages.backends.s3boto3.S3StaticStorage",
    },
}

and it worked fine.
